# App publicado para Windows Phone não instala nos aparelhos

Tags: mobile, windows-phone, app, windows-phone-8-1

Galera,

Estou com um problema em um APP desenvolvido por mim para a plataforma Windows Phone.

Ele está na Windows Store, porém os usuários não conseguem instalá-lo em seus aparelhos. O erro dado não é sucinto e não consigo detectar o motivo deste problema.

O app que desenvolvi se encontra em:
https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/store/apps/treino-da-academia/9nblggh6gs76

Alguém tem alguma idéia de qual o problema?

Valeu!

Comment: Vc tem informações a respeito do erro?

Answer (score 1):

Já passei por isso, o melhor que tens a fazer é voltar a criar um novo packeged com Build em Release e a Plataform com ARM e depois volta a publicar.